# Click events in a jQuery Dialog occur twice?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-ui, dom

I have been dealing with an odd problem that `.click()` events happen twice whenever placed in a jQuery Dialog.

My simple test case is below and a [live example is here](http://jsbin.com/ebiqe/3)

```
  <div id="popup" style="display: none">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="testlink">Test Link</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#testlink').click(function(){
        alert("Test Link clicked");
        return 0;
      });
    </script>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#popup').css('display','block');
    var h=($(window).height()+0.0)*0.9;
    var w=($(window).width()+0.0)*0.9;
    if(w >= 800){
      w = 800;
    }
    $('#popup').dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      width: w,
      height: h,
      modal: true,
      open: function(event,ui){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
      },
      close: function(event,ui){
        $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the `<script>` block that registers the click event outside of the `popup` div, I think the JS gets parsed another time when the div becomes visible...

Comment: Huh. I didn't get the double call running locally with your slim sample, but I did get it on your live sample running on your machine. Your sample site has some extra stuff going on too.

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason, why this happens, is that your script is parsed 2 times. If you are not sure, where this happens or have no time to debug, here's a simple workaround.

The idea is to remove all active hadlers, before a new hadler is applied.

```
$( '.selector' ).unbind( 'click' ).click( function() {
    // your code
});
```

If you use jQuery 1.7 or above, you can use the following syntax.

```
$( '.selector' ).off( 'click' ).on( 'click', function() {
    // your code
});
```