# jQuery logic firing twice from a Usercontrol when used in a jQueryUI modal dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, user-controls

I have an asp.net usercontrol that I'm using to put a bunch of HTML and Jquery logic into to be shared on several pages. This usercontrol has some dropdown boxes loaded from json calls and has no added codebehind logic.

When I use this usercontrol on a normal page it works perfectly fine, and no issues at all.

However, when I wrap the usercontrol in a div, and use a jqueryUI modal dialog, everything in the usercontrol fires twice. Not only code in the initial $(document).ready(function() {});, but also every function is also fired twice when called.

Debugging this in Visual Studio, I see that everything is first being called from the external JS file, and then again from a "script block" file that is somehow getting generated on the fly.

This script block file isn't getting generated on a page that doesn't wrap the user control in a modal.

The same happens if I use IISExpress or IIS7.

The question is, why is this script block file getting created, and why is all my jQuery logic firing twice?

--edit--

Here is the div:

```
  <div id="divMyDiv" title="MyDiv">
     <uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="MyUsercontrol" />
</div>
```

Here is the modal logic that uses it:

```
        $("#divMyDiv").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });
```

Note: The problm still occurs, even if I remove the "open:" function. But, it does **not** occur if I remove the entire dialog block, so it is specific to this dialog call.

Comment: Can you elaborate more with some code that wraps with Div? Do you use update panel and doing partial page rendering? Seems like there is something binds the events again when you add DIV.

Comment: Sure,  I updated the question with the div, usercontrol, and jquery call in question.  There are no update panels or any other asp.net ajax calls on this page.

Comment: I think you have more than one user control instance in same page. So you would be having two or more ready function or what ever scripts you written inside user control. Please check with view source!

Comment: Check this existing post. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142504/click-events-in-a-jquery-dialog-occur-twice

may be helpful to you

Comment: @Murali That's actually one of the first things I checked. There's only one instance of the control, and nothing from the usercontrol appears in the page source more than once.

Comment: Is that external file is jQueryUI.js? or Microsoft helper js file? can you put some code getting executing from that file here? Sometime asp.net binds some events based on the attributes added to the control, for making unobstructive javascript :)

Comment: @Murali There is a file called "Script Block" getting generated on the fly, and that is where this extra call is getting executed. But, I don't know why this file is generated only when using the dialog calls, or how to prevent it from executing anything again in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine what was going on.

The link to the external JavaScript file was within the user control itself. Moving this link out of the user control and into the main page fixed it.

For whatever reason, this stopped that dynamic script block file from getting generated, and as a result, also stopped calling every function twice.

I just need to remember to add this JavaScript link to every page that uses this user control, or add it to my master page.

If anyone understands why this happens, I would love to know.

Answer (score 1):

See if java-script/jQuery written on user control it will be loaded every time on your landing page.

And will have multiple copies of the same javascript/jQuery code on your landing page.

If you will load your user-control more then one the script will be fired more than one.

It will be fired as many time as you will load the user control.

To overcome this place the jQuery call on the landing page.

And on load bind your jQuery with the user control.

Edit 1

I know that you are having only one instance of the user-control.

My points are

1. You are opening a user control on the page
2. user control are have a jQuery call
3. jQuery call will be a part of the landing page if you will open dialog
4. you will close the dialog
5. your jQuery is still a part of your landing page
6. again you open a dialog
7. the second copy of your jQuery written on your user control loaded to your landing page
8. now you have two copies of your jQuery code
9. and as may time you will open and close there will be as may copies

I think this is the problem.

Comment: There is only one instance of the user contol on the page. It also  correctly fires only one time when the jQueryUI dialog function is not called.

Comment: as far my uderstanding you will open and close your dilog on the page. right? And every time when you open your user control on the model popup it's javascript will be a part of your landing page. But when you will close the popup it will bot be gone from your landing page.

Comment: This isn't a true dialog box. The usercontrol in this case always exists on the page. The div that contains it is just getting hidden and displayed as needed. I also confirmed that the usercontrol itself isn't getting reloaded by setting a break on it's page_load as well as watching the raw http traffic.